# Do popular linux distributions verify binary packages?

Tags: security, package-management, distributions

If not all package builds are reproducible, what guarantees that users do not run two different binaries of the same version and architecture?

Comment: Could you provide examples of the type of problem you're thinking of?  It's not clear to me what you're asking.  May make sense to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to verify that a binary package does what the source says it should do (it's an unsolvable problem both in theory and in practice). However, if you know how the binary package was produced, you may be able to be certain that it was the result of compiling the source code. This requires trusting:

1. the compilation tools (not just compilers as such but also all other tools involved in the build process such as `make`, `tar`, etc.): you need to [trust that they did their job properly](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/thompson/trust.html);
2. the machine(s) on which the compilation took place (you need to trust that they executed the compilation tools as intended);
3. the distribution chain from the machine on which the compilation took place to the machine where you use the package.

Major distributions build binary packages on tightly-controlled infrastructure (only a few administrators have access to those machines), using compilers that come from the distribution itself (hence so as long as no compiler is buggy or backdoored and no build of a compiler from a compromised machine is used, no problem will ever appear). When the package is built, the same machine (or a machine running in the same tightly-controlled infrastructure) signs it cryptographically. The cryptographic signature ensures that the packages that get installed on the end-user machines are exactly the packages that were produced on the build infrastructure. All major package management tools (apt, yum, dnf, etc.) verify package signatures.

Thus the distribution itself doesn't verify (1) (it can't), and ensures (2) rather than verifying it, but the distribution verifies (3).

Reproducible builds help with (2): they provide an independent verification that the build happened as intended, and thus they protect against a compromise of the build infrastructure.

Schemes for independent compilation have been proposed for (1), but they are rarely practical: most languages don't have independent implementations.

Comment: +1 soley for the link to Thompson's "Reflections on Trusting Trust"